# SQL to flat-file export

Tags: sql, ssis, automation, header, flat-file

I working on a report where I have my query in SQL and the query result is to be exported to a flat file.

-- This is a daily job and every day the result is exported to a new flat file

```
(Name of the flat file & date : NAME_OF_THE_FLATFILE_7.17.2017.txt).
```

-- That flat file has a header template with 9 rows. out of which few are static and the rest are dynamic. The header dynamic rows includes Date, No. of query result rows, Name of the flat file and so...

> My Questions:
>
> 1. Is there a way to export data from SQL to flat file with the above specified name? (we are not supposed to use Stored procedures. I know we have a process of exporting the query result from SQL to flat file using SSIS, but is it possible to export the query result every day with the specified name format?)
> 2. How do I query the header template and have it exported to the flat file?

The output of the text file im expecting is

```
Header          Execution Date  20170717

Header          Text file name  NAME_OF_THE_FLATFILE_07.17.2017

Header          Count of rows   5

Header          Dynamic row

Header          Dynamic row

Header          Dynamic row

Header          Dynamic row

Header          Dynamic row

Header          Dynamic row

Client      Loan Number

123     4567890123

234     5678901234

345     6789012345

456     7890123456

567     8901234567
```

Comment: I'd use C# to do this. Load the results into a data table and then run the data table through a csv generation function.

Comment: Dynamic headers are typical not a great process as they are difficult to consume.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to do this without using additional tools (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Export/147145/. If you need to email the result of a TSQL query, I use dbo.sp_send_dbmail. I have a report that does this in Excel but you can certainly change it to a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamically naming the file is easy, you would just use an expression in the destination connection.

But to create the layout you want, you would need to do this with a script task that creates the file, opens it as a filestream, and writes the file line by line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I was able to figure out the expression in the destination connection.
Can you help me with how to query the header template and have it exported to the flat file using script task?